# Exchange values between classes/Methods

Tags: java, loops, class, methods

i recently learned the use of public, private and double in my different classes. But for some reason i cant understand why this is not working. My intention was to use three different classes as an exercise: I want Do() to make numbers from 0 to 20 and show only the numbers 0 till 10 on my console using the method for1() in a different class. Can someone please fix this issue? I dont need a shorter code or a code in just 1 class since i need it to educate myself using many classes. I would thank anyone if you could fix this issue using this kind of setup. Thanks in advance.

```
public class MainM {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        loop Q = new loop();
        Q.Do();
    }
}
//------------------------------------------------------
public class loop {
    public double b;
    Sum R = new Sum();   // Java shows the problem is here : at Sum.<init>(Sum.java:3)
    public void Do() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            b = b + 2;
            if (b <= 10) {
                R.for1();
            }
        }
    }
}
//--------------------------------------------------
public class Sum {
    loop Q = new loop();
    public void for1() {
        System.out.println("b " + Q.b);
    }
}
```

Comment: a new loop creates a new Sum which creates a new loop which creates a new ...    Guessing you got a StackOverflowException

Comment: How can i fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have your Sum class only with the print statement and the method for1() should have one parameter. Bellow is my suggestion

```
public class Sum {
  public void for1(double b) {
    System.out.println("b " + b);
  }
}
```

And your loop class will be

```
public class loop {
  public double b;
  Sum R = new Sum();

  public void Do() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      b = b + 2;
      if (b <= 10) {
          R.for1(b);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is great but if i got multiple variables, do i create an array with those values and do it like ... R.for1(array[]);...? or is there a better way?

Comment: You can use an array or a list if you have a lot of parameters. I suggest you start reading about Object-Oriented programming and see code examples to understand the concepts and it will be easier to use objects' fields and methods properly